# imagettfbbox: syntax correct in testing machine, not in server

Tags: php, syntax, gd

I'm working on a small site that generates an image with the user's text input overlaid on it.
I've been using XAMPP to develop it in my local machine, but it doesn't work on the company's server. I have checked that GD and Freetype are both installed properly, and the PNG support is enabled for GD.

Strangely, the error I get is:
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in /buddy.php on line 15

The code is as follows:

```
<?php 
header('Content-type: image/png');
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');

if (isset($_GET['dataval']))
{
    $myText = $_GET['dataval'];
    $im = @imagecreatefromjpeg ('assets/images/wig.jpg');       
    $white = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255);
    $myText = mb_strtoupper($myText, 'UTF-8');
    $font = 'PassingNotes.ttf';

    if (strlen($myText) < 24)
    {
```

The next line is Line 15

```
        $textW = imagettfbbox(80, 5, 'PassingNotes.ttf', $myText)[4]; 
        if ($textW >= 680)
        {
            $myText = SplitInBounds($myText, 80, 680);  
            error_log('text: '. $myText);
        }
        imagettftext($im, 80, 5, 230, 380, $white, 'PassingNotes.ttf', $myText);
    }
```

Honestly, I have no idea what's going on. The code is exactly the same in my computer and the server, and it works fine in my computer.

Comment: It doesn't seem to like you referencing an array returned from a function all within one line. Try assigning the returned array from `imagettfbbox` to a var and then referencing that, i.e. `$myvar[4]`. Perhaps this is a PHP version thing.

Comment: Utkanos, it worked! Thanks :D

Indeed, my local version is 5.5, the server is 5.2